# How to uninstall Visual Studio 2017 update 15.3

Tags: visual-studio-2017

After upgrading to VS 2017 15.3 my solution compiles, but .NET Framework 4.6.2 projects in the same solution (e.g. Specflow Acceptance tests) have loads of compiler warnings and missing references. When acceptance tests are run they present an error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

I don't have time to fix this now, so how can I rollback the Visual Studio 2017 installation to 15.2?

Other answers (for previous versions of Visual Studio) suggest using the "View installed updates" thing in Control Panel, but I don't see any VS 2017 updates in there.

Comment: I've had sever, unsolvable issues with WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData crashing when building and running just after upgrading to 15.3. I need to rollback to 15.0 also!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft recently introduced breaking changes with version 15.5, so we had to find a way to downgrade from that.

While I'm not sure it's relevant for OP's original problem, this would have been relevant at the time the question was posed, so leaving this for future reference:

Microsoft *do* provide a way of downgrading to the version before the latest (N-1), in this case version 15.4.5, so you don't have to go all the way to 15.0:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Answer (score 7):

I could not find a way to do this. In the end I had to uninstall VS 2017 completely and install VS 2017 15.0 from this link:

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=2210

Answer (score 3):

This most recent 15.3.3 update seems to be severely borked.  I'm working through trying to uninstall extensions and extra features in /safemode to see if I can get it to start without crashing on launch, but I'm not hopeful.

Probably going to have to burn it down and start over.